# Issues with screen’s FrameRates on different devices (Low-end and high-end)

Tags: three.js, game-development, react-three-fiber, cannon.js

I am developing a simple game, in which the player are just simple spherical balls which are moving in a particular direction with same velocity avoiding the obstacle. the user can control the movement of balls in left and right direction only, just like temple run to avoid obstacle. I’ve integrated cannon.js over three.js for physics. Issues i am getting are: -

1. I have some obstacle that has animations, i’ve created physics world obstacle following the same animation and synced both. When the player Balls touches it, the screen stucks due to recieveing multiple callbacks of arround 400 and above and all balls gets destroyed. I want to destroy single-single balls.
2. The Main issue is that, when running on different devices, On PC’s having framerates of 75fps, its working fine. But on mobile Phones having 60Fps or less. Its running very slow due to which the Gsap’s Duration is also not working good. The velocity of jumping am giving is not reached in low performance devices such as mobile phones.

Did anyone know how can i sync physics to work same on different devices also?